# Convert Android Eclipse projects to visual studio 2012?

Tags: android, eclipse, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to convert eclipse projects to visual studio 2012?  I have a bunch
of eclipse example projects, but I have visual studio 2012 with xamarin.

Comment: Xamarin is c# I don't think exists a tool to convert java to c#...

Comment: Why don't you try Android Studio? It's a lot more efficient to work in that IDE rather than Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse projects that you are talking about are mostly java projects. Visual studio Xamarin work with c#. You wont be able to open those samples in visual studio directly. Your approach of opening an android or a similar project from eclipse into Visual Studio using Xamarin is not right.
The structure is different. 
You need to port all code from java to c# and have a separate c# xamarin project and open it in Visual studio.

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use a tool like Sharpen to convert Java Syntax to C#
(see http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/porting_java_to_csharp/)

But detailed platform differences and project/solution structural differences would have to be handled manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to convert Java to C#:

- [Xamarin XobotOS Sharpen (using Eclipse plugin)](https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS)
- [Mono Sharpen (without Eclipse)](https://github.com/mono/sharpen#building-and-testing-sharpen-itself)
- [Tangible Software Solutions](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Java_to_CSharp_Converter.html)

I am currently checking which one is the best, but it looks like the second one looks better because you don't need ***Eclipse*** and lots of people are now developing on ***Android Studio***.
The third one could be great but the free version looks quite limited.

I will update mi answer when i'll be done with it!

Bye